# Probability problem involving Bayes' theorem and tree diagrams

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

There are two slot machines. The probability of winning with machine 1 is 0.1 and the probability of winning with machine 2 is 0.5. If you try a machine at random, lose and want to play again, should you switch?

I tried using Bayes' theorem and the result is that there is a higher chance of having picked machine 1, so you should switch. But when I made a tree diagram, I get the same probability of winning the second time whether you switch or not. Can anyone explain?

Comment: It’s definitely better to switch. Can you show your tree diagram?

Comment: It would help if you show your work!